# Let $R$ a commutative ring and let $a\in R$. What does $aR$ mean?

Tags: ring-theory, notation

Let $R$ a commutative ring and let $a\in R$. What does $aR$ mean ?

I would think it means $\{ar : r \in R \}$ as that was the meaning in group theory. The thing that confuses me is that in group theory $aR=R$, isn't this true for rings ?

Comment: Nice Question... Do you see  what is the difference between "Commutative ring" and "Field"???

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, a field as has multiplicative inverse and multiplicative identity, if I recall correctly.

Comment: $2 \mathbb Z \ne \mathbb Z$. Why?

Comment: Focus on "Multiplicative Inverse"...In a field, given any $a\neq 0$ we have some $b\in F$ such that $ab=ba=1$.... If for any ring $R$ and $a\neq0$ in $R$, $aR=R$ then, we should have $ab=1$ which implies each ring is a field....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Why does $a≠0$ and $aR=R$ implies $ab=1$ ?

Comment: I understand the fact now that $aR ≠R$ in general. But I don't see why you need to have a field to make $aR=R$.

Comment: $aR=R$ and $1\in R$ So, $1\in aR=\{ab : b\in R\}$  so, for some $b\in R$ we should have $ab=1$.. because of commutativenes, $ab=ba=1$..

Comment: I am not saying that you "need to have field" to make $aR=R$.. But, if $aR=R$ for all $a\in R$ then $R$ should be a field and if $R$ is just a commutative ring and not a field there should exist some $a\in R$ for which $aR\neq R$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik aaah, I understand it now, that makes sense. thanks !

Comment: You are welcome!!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, $aR$ is usually defined as $\{ar: r\in R\}$ and is the *ideal* generated by $a$. You are not quite right about fields, though: If $R$ is a field and $a=0$, then $aR\ne R$. And indeed, that is because $0$ is *not* a unit in $R$. In general rings, there might be less units even. Think of $\mathbb Z$ for instance, certainly $2\mathbb Z\ne \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I would say that $0R≠R$ because $0R=\{0 \}$. I don't see why this has to do with the fact that $0$ is not a unit.

Comment: Well, $aR=R$ for fields only because for every $r\in R$, you can write $r=a(a^{-1}r)$. If $a$ is not a unit, then this fails. I am very certain of the above *"because"*, the one in my answer might be a bit bold. Still, the equality $aR=R$ holds if and only if $a$ is a unit.

Answer (score 0):

Remember rings are not groups, they have a group structure under addition but NOT necessarily under multiplication.

If you were considering $a+R$ in a ring then yes this would be $R$ since we have a group structure for addition.

However in the case of multiplication $aR$ will be $R$ if and only if $a$ has a **multiplicative** inverse.

e.g. $R=\mathbb{Z}$. The elements that have a multiplicative inverse are $\pm 1$ and you notice that $-\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ yet everything else creates a proper subset of multiples of an element, for example $a=2$ gives the set $2\mathbb{Z}$ of even numbers, which certainly isn't $\mathbb{Z}$.